# ASP.NET database entity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, system.data

I have big problem with MVC5. I am doing tutorial MVC MusicStore and I got a problem with databse.
I have to add

```
using system.data.entity
```

But Viusual don't know what is the entity. I was searching information about this problem and there was only that, but it's still don't work...

```
<add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
```

Any ideas how can i fixed it?

Answer (score -1):

To install EntityFramework 4.3.1, run following command in Package manager console (open VS2010/12/13, go to Tools → Library Package Manager → Package Manager Console):

```
Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 4.3.1
```